# Export Application List from LInux Mint Startmenu

Tags: cinnamon

Is it possible to export to a text file a list with all the applications that appear in Linux Mint Startmenu ?
I need that in order to know what programs there are installed on my PC (without dependencies and lots of packages).
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have Cinnamon as your UI.

Have a look into `~/.config/menus/cinnamon-applications.menu`

Here are mappings between Menu category and Menu Items.

In `~/.local/share/applications`

Here are menu items configured in `*.desktop` files.

Be aware that these directories contain only your user created entries.

---

Cinnamon has a similar structure for the general menu as well and merges this:

In `/etc/xdg/menus/cinnamon-applications.menu` are the shared menu categories.

In `/usr/share/applications` are the menu entries of all installed applications (uncategorized)

Comment: Yes indeed I have cinnamon.
Unfortunately I found nothing in the three paths you mentioned. There are all folders existing in the Mint Menu, like: Accessories, Games, Graphics, etc. But the installed applications cannot be found anywhere.

Comment: Did you check the following two directories /usr/share/applications and /usr/share/app-install/desktop/ ? I guess the first are the pre-installed, and the second are the ready-to-install apps.

Comment: if there's nothing in there in your installation, try following command in a terminal: sudo find / -name "*.desktop"

Comment: Well, all installed programs can be found here:  /usr/share/applications.Too bad, they are not categorized in directories, as they are in the Mint Menu. Anyway it helped. Thx. 
I guess there is no software to export the Mint Menu after all.